# return information using pexpect

Tags: pexpect

I am learning how to use pexpect and i had a question. I am trying to find the version number of a remote server and based on that version number I want to choose the right driver number. I am not entirely sure how should I go about doing this. Something along the lines of a getline function. Let me know if there are any functions I could use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child `.before` and `.after` properties contain the stdout before resp. after the matched expectation.

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('cat /etc/issue')
child.expect('Ubuntu.*')
print(child.after)
```

Which of the commands requires input? If it is the driver installation you could use fabric & fexpect:

```
from ilogue.fexpect import expect, expecting, run

output = run('get-system-version')

prompts = []
prompts += expect('Which driver version do you want to install?',output)

with expecting(prompts):
    run('install-driver-command')
```

Comment: The idea is to do a `cat /etc/issue` and check the version number(using regex). So what I want is to be able to get the output of `cat /etc/issue` 

i cant use fabric or fexpect since I am building upon previous work which is all done in pexpect :(

Comment: Ok i have added an example; try this script